# How are java dependencies deployed on server machine

Tags: java, maven

Did a lot of research but could not find a proper answer. My question is simple - I am building an executable jar file which has few external dependencies like spring etc. Now I want to deploy my executable jar file to server machine. Is there a easy and safe way of achieving it? Few options I am aware of:

1. Build an uber jar with all the dependencies bundled along with application code and deploy it
2. Deploy the source code executable jar and then manually add all the dependency jar files to the class path

Is there any other better way? Any tools which can help here? How are dependency jar upgrades handled? - Are they manually replaced on server machine?

Comment: Neither way is good or serviceable.  Realistically, you'd use a configuration file or script to control the dependencies on the server (Ansible for example).  For a test environment I'd just set up a simple bash shell script.

Comment: Yes, I agree neither way mentioned above in the question is good. So other than having our own custom scripts there is no other industry standards that are followed here in deployment ?

Comment: why cant you try docker??

Answer (score 0):

If you 'just' have an executable jar and some other jar files as dependencies (this is the most common case actually), you can follow best practice standards and create a zip file containing them all. Check how various open source projects offer their stuff for download.

If you use some framework that might also guide you about deployment. As an example, the [servlet specification](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr369/index.html) tells you how to create that zip file in chapter 10.

If you want another way more compliant to the OS package manager, you could take a look at [JPackage](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/jpackage/packaging-overview.html). It also bundles a Java Runtime so you have tight control not just about the jar dependencies but also the runtime.